# CATEGORY filter appearing two times

Tags: category, layered-navigation, category-listing

In Layered navigation There are two filters of same name appearing two times how can I remove the above one:
[image: KATEGORI]

We want to remove the first CATEGORY FILTER AND make the second to be displayed only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use [template path hints](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/template-path-hints.html), it will show you which template display the category filter. Once you identify the template, then you can easily override the template and remove the filter or if it is coming from the particular theme/extension, then check admin configuration related to the particular extension/theme to disable that part.

Comment: after enabling template path hints it's  not enabled showing no path